# Image Swap wont work in Firefox But works in IE

Tags: html, image, click, dreamweaver, swap

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to coding but have been in the process of setting up my own webpage via Dreamweaver as the WYSIWYG approach waorks for me.  The problem is I am trying to implement a disjointed image swap on click event.. It works fone for me on IE but not on firefox, and have been tearing my hair out trying to find a solution to no avail..  heres a link to the page in question

http://www.sdmkdesign.com/central%20drive.html#

I would be grateful if anyone could help.

Many thanks

Sk

Answer (score 2):

the problem is this element:

```
<div id="linetopdiv"></div>
```

Its overlaying the elements with a transparent layer which is killing your ability to click on the elements beneath

for example, if you added a z-index like this it would work:

```
<div id="linetopdiv" style="z-index: -1;"></div>
```

Obviously thats just an inline hack but it should point you in the right direction

Comment: Seengee, 

Doh! a massive oversight on my part, the div was added at a later stage and I didnt even change the z index.  Small thing that I forgot to change.. many thanks for the quick response.. Problem solved!